# What are EJB callbacks and why do we need them?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I'm just started to look at Java EE but I'm struggling to understand what callbacks are exactly and what they are used for.

Does anyone have a clear explanation of what they are? I've looked around the site but been unable to find much information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callbacks are your primary opportunity to execute custom code at specific points in the EJB (or the container's lifecycle).

So take for example, you want to initialize specific fields or components

- *inside* the EJB,
- *after* the EJB has been instantiated, but
- *before* it starts to service requests

You'll implement the `@PostConstruct` callback method. A method annotated with this is an advertisement to the JavaEE runtime that that method must be run immediately after an instance of that class has been created. A common use of this annotation is to instamtiate class-level variables or to prepare shared resources.

The JavaEE specification has designated several annotations such as this one, as lifecycle callbacks. What this means is that at startup, the container knows to scan the deployment kit for artifacts that implement any of the available callbacks. In doing so, it knows to notify the interested components (EJBs, CDI components , JAX-WS bean implementations) of specific events, or call specific methods when...specific actions occur in the app server.

The callback mechanism is in itself an implementation of the Callback pattern (or event-driven programming if you're coming from a UI programming world)

**Further Reading:**

- [Oracle's intro to lifecycle callbacks](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bnbog/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

**The Formal Definition**

> Callback is a mechanism by which life cycle of an enterprise bean can be intercepted.

**A Practical Example**

I think a single example will help show off the usefulness of these callback annotations. Let's take a look at the `@PreDestroy` callback. From the JBoss docs on EJB, we can see that:

> PreDestroy - is invoked when the bean is removed from the pool or destroyed.

And you've got a Bean that has some kind of File Resource. You want to ensure that when the Bean is destroyed, that file lock goes with it. Well, we know that it's "risky" practise to wait for the Garbage Collector to handle these things for us; we don't know when it's going to run.

But what we can do is put in place some logic that is called when the bean is removed.

```
@PreDestroy
public void cleanUp() {
    // Clean up your FileOutputStreams etc.
}
```

In your bean, it's very clear that this method is executed when the bean is destroyed and it requires no extra code from the outside. This ensures that your resources are cleaned up, as and when the bean is destroyed.